# List of Authenticated Users

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, authentication, google-api

I am working on a tool inside of a current iOS app that I only want to be available to a handful of people. The company email addresses are all gmail.

How can I make the app work in a way that, You sign into your google account, and on the server end it will check if you have access or not. If you do, it will then move on to the tool page.

Does Google API have anything on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine has the [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) which you can use to allow people to log in with a Google Account. You can the write server side code to cross check the logged in email address against your whitelist (which may or may not be configurable), and only allow access if the emails match.

Is that the kind of thing you mean?